# What is the correct form of arguments to Python subprocess()

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I need to convert an existing short wav file to mp3 (wma would also be acceptable).

I have installed ffmpeg in the C: directory as recommended, and it works when used directly from a Windows command line, but not in Python 2.7

At first I used `os.system()` but although the code doesn't create an error, it does not create the mp3 file either

Using the preferred `subprocess.call()` gives an error message.

This one of several attempts to make it work:

```
import os,sys
import subprocess

# .wav file exists and contains 1 minute of audio
os.system('ffmpeg -i G:/Channel1_08.wav G:/Channel1_08.mp3')
# line above executes but does not create an mp3 file
# the same command works in a Windows command line
# ffmpeg is in the C: directory

## subprocess is supposed to be better than os.system, I tried
s = subprocess.call("ffmpeg -i G:/Channel1_08.wav G:/Channel1_08.mp3",shell = True)
# line above returns s=1, but no mp3 file
```

Edit: more info, I'm using a Win8.1 PC, the files are on a USB stick.
with other variations of the argument string, I often get "file not found" errors, but the file is definitely in place.
It occurs to me that I have not re-booted the PC since changing the PATH variable. I cannot do this until a major search script has finished running  in about 24 hours time. I'll keep you posted.

14 Sep 17: Rebooting fixed the problem. For the record the original wav file was 2113KB, the wma is 1101KB and the mp3 is 199KB.

Comment: A non-zero return code is usually indicative of an error.

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_call` to get an exception immediately on failure, rather than having to check the return code.

Comment: The *preferred* form would be `call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "G:/Channel1_08.wav", "G:/Channel1_08.mp3"])` and leave the shell out of it.

Comment: The `os.system()` call should have worked.  Is `ffmpeg.exe` in your PATH?

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses!

Comment: To chepner, I tried your suggestion, but got a WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified. But the file IS there, I can play it.

Comment: To John G:  Yes, in fact it is teh only item in the path variable. If it were not correctly written to PATH I think the the direct command line not have worked.